# How to shrink the storage size limit of IPFS?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, ipfs

I am using IPFS and trying to understand its structure.

**ISSUE: 1**
The issue I am facing is that when I am trying to shrink the storage size of IPFS (for testing it is taking so long time, hence I just want to shrink File System for a while) but is unable to shrink.

I tried to configure the **config file** by changing the **StorageMax** limit
using this command

> ipfs config Datastore.StorageMax 1GB

but still it does not work, it accepting (ipfs add ) the files after the 1GB also, why he is not limiting the file-storage?

anyone, please suggest me How to reduce file-system size?

**ISSUE: 2**
Even in case of IPFS's default storage limit (Which is 10 GB), I saw when I am adding the files on IPFS it is not stopping to store files after crosses 10GB (which was limit). 
It should not be cross after the limit ends, for this what to do?

below is the config file

```
{
  "API": {
    "HTTPHeaders": {}
  },
  "Addresses": {
    "API": "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/5001",
    "Announce": [],
    "Gateway": "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/8080",
    "NoAnnounce": [],
    "Swarm": [
      "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/4001",
      "/ip6/::/tcp/4001"
    ]
  },
  "Bootstrap": [
    "/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io/ipfs/QmNnooDu7bfjPFoTZYxMWUQJyrVwtbZg5gBMjTezGAJN",
    "/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io/ipfs/QmQCU2EcMqAqQPR2i9bChGNJchTbq5TbXJJ16u19uLTa",
    "/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io/ipfs/QmbLHAnMoJPWSCR5Zhtx6BX9KiKNN6tpvbUcqanj75Nb",
    "/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io/ipfs/QmcZf59bWwK5XFi76CZX8cbBhTzzA3gU1ZjYZcYW3dwt",
    "/ip4/104.131.131.82/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmaCpDMGvV2BGHeYERUEQAwe3N8SzbUtfsmvsqQLuvuJ",
    "/ip4/104.236.179.241/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLPppuBtQSGwKDZT2MULpjvfd3aZ6ha4oFGL1KrGM",
    "/ip4/128.199.219.111/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLSafTMBsPKadTEgaXDQVcqN88CNLHXMkTNwMKPnu",
    "/ip4/104.236.76.40/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLV4Bbm51jM9C4gDYZCy3U6aXMJDAbzgu2fzaDs64",
    "/ip4/178.62.158.247/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLer265NRgSp2LA3dPakiS1J6DifTC88f5uVQKNAd",
    "/ip6/2604:a880:1:20::203:d001/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLPppuBtQSGwKDZT2M7Lpjvfd3aZ6ha4oFGL1KrGM",
    "/ip6/2400:6180:0:d0::151:6001/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLSafTMBsPKadTEgaXctVcqN88CNLHXMkTNwMKPnu",
    "/ip6/2604:a880:800:10::4a:5001/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLV4Bbm51jM9C4gDYZQ9Cy3U6aXMJDAbzgu2fzaDs64",
    "/ip6/2a03:b0c0:0:1010::23:1001/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmSoLer265NRgSp2LA3dPaeykiS1J6DifTC88f5uVQKNAd"
  ],
  "Datastore": {
    "BloomFilterSize": 0,
    "GCPeriod": "1h",
    "HashOnRead": false,
    "Spec": {
      "mounts": [
        {
          "child": {
            "path": "blocks",
            "shardFunc": "/repo/flatfs/shard/v1/next-to-last/2",
            "sync": true,
            "type": "flatfs"
          },
          "mountpoint": "/blocks",
          "prefix": "flatfs.datastore",
          "type": "measure"
        },
        {
          "child": {
            "compression": "none",
            "path": "datastore",
            "type": "levelds"
          },
          "mountpoint": "/",
          "prefix": "leveldb.datastore",
          "type": "measure"
        }
      ],
      "type": "mount"
    },
    "StorageGCWatermark": 0,
    "StorageMax": "1GB"
  },
  "Discovery": {
    "MDNS": {
      "Enabled": true,
      "Interval": 10
    }
  },
  "Experimental": {
    "FilestoreEnabled": false,
    "Libp2pStreamMounting": false,
    "P2pHttpProxy": false,
    "QUIC": false,
    "ShardingEnabled": false,
    "UrlstoreEnabled": false
  },
  "Gateway": {
    "APICommands": [],
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": [
        "X-Requested-With",
        "Range"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": [
        "GET"
      ],
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    "PathPrefixes": [],
    "RootRedirect": "",
    "Writable": false
  },
  "Identity": {
    "PeerID": "QmfB8xVzjndgMWHuxszYADGrwBo1Zx6zjBQQCsqARDupsW"
  },
  "Ipns": {
    "RecordLifetime": "",
    "RepublishPeriod": "",
    "ResolveCacheSize": 128
  },
  "Mounts": {
    "FuseAllowOther": false,
    "IPFS": "/ipfs",
    "IPNS": "/ipns"
  },
  "Pubsub": {
    "DisableSigning": false,
    "Router": "",
    "StrictSignatureVerification": false
  },
  "Reprovider": {
    "Interval": "12h",
    "Strategy": "all"
  },
  "Routing": {
    "Type": "dht"
  },
  "Swarm": {
    "AddrFilters": null,
    "ConnMgr": {
      "GracePeriod": "20s",
      "HighWater": 900,
      "LowWater": 600,
      "Type": "basic"
    },
    "DisableBandwidthMetrics": false,
    "DisableNatPortMap": false,
    "DisableRelay": false,
    "EnableRelayHop": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `StorageMax` [does not actually limit](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/config.md#datastore) [the size of the IPFS node](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/issues/3066#issuecomment-343036019), instead it's used to determine whether or not to run garbage collection. IPFS will write until the disk is full.

Comment: `IPFS will write until the disk is full.` do you mean, the actual Host machine's disk or disk which is provided to IPFS? @michaelavila

Comment: @YuvrajTakey you don't upload to IPFS anything, it's not a hosting service.